# Function which outputs several std::collections to CSV / row first iteration

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

I want to write a function with the following signature (or similar):

```
template <typename... Ts>
void collection_to_csv(const std::string filepath, const Ts& ... containers);
```

The function should write a csv file to a file located at `filepath`, where containers can be any number of iteratable containers from the STD and would define the columns of the outputted CSV file. E.g. I could use it like this:

```
std::vector<int> column1{1, 2, 3, 4};
std::list<float> column2{1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5};
collections_to_csv(someFilePath, c1, c2);
```

Is this possible? So far I've been trying to use variadic templates like so:

```
    template <typename... Ts>
    void collection_to_csv(const std::string filepath, std::initializer_list<std::string> headers, const Ts& ... containers)
    {
        std::ofstream file;
        file.open(filepath, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);

        for (std::size_t irow=0; irow < size; ++irow)
        {
            for (const auto& container : containers) //But how to iterate through the variadic arguments when they could be different types?
            {
                file << container[i] << ",";
            }
        }

        file.flush();
        file.close();
    }
```

Everything I've seen about variadic templates suggests they're 'iterated' using recursion but this would force a 'column first' iteration order. I need a 'row first' order, making me think variadic templates might be the wrong tool here. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::tuple` to store the iterator of each `containers` and then use `std::apply` to increment them one by one to do this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

template <typename... Ts>
void collection_to_csv(const Ts&... containers) {
  const auto ncol = [](const auto& first, const auto&...) { 
    return first.size(); 
  }(containers...);

  auto iters = std::make_tuple(containers.begin()...);

  for (std::size_t icol = 0; icol < ncol; ++icol) {
    std::apply(
      [&](auto&... iter) { 
        ((std::cout << *iter++ << ","), ...); 
    }, iters);
    std::cout << "\n";
  }
}

int main() {
  std::vector column1{1, 2, 3, 4};
  std::list column2{1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5};
  collection_to_csv(column1, column2);
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/axf9xovdG)

Thanks to the introduction of C++23 [`views::zip`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/range.zip.view), `collection_to_csv` can be implemented more simply just using `views::zip`, that is, zip all `containers` and iterate their elements one by one.

```
#include <ranges>
#include <tuple>

template <typename... Ts>
void collection_to_csv(const Ts&... containers) {
  for (const auto& values : std::ranges::zip_view(containers...)) {
    std::apply(
      [](const auto&... value) { ((std::cout << value << ","), ...); }, values);
    std::cout << "\n";
  }
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/cdTarGWfr)

Comment: Great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using a helper function with `std::index_sequence` and unpacking on a lambda expression you can get it to work like [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1b9Ph1ro3):

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <typename... TIters, std::size_t... Indices>
void collections_to_csv_helper(std::tuple<TIters...> begins,
                               std::tuple<TIters...> ends,
                               std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
    auto currents = begins;
    while (((std::get<Indices>(currents) != std::get<Indices>(ends)) && ...)) {
        (([&] {
             auto& current = std::get<Indices>(currents);
             std::cout << *current << '\t';
             current++;
         }()),
         ...);

        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

template <typename... Containers>
void collections_to_csv(const Containers&... containers) {
    collections_to_csv_helper(std::tuple{containers.begin()...},
                              std::tuple{containers.end()...},
                              std::index_sequence_for<Containers...>{});
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> column1{1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::list<float> column2{1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5};
    collections_to_csv(column1, column2);
}
```

Output:

```
1   1.5 
2   2.5 
3   3.5 
4   4.5
```

Note, that it goes up to the **shortest** list and ignores the rest of the other lists.

Alternatively there are also some non-standard zip methods that can zip multiple collections in a single iterator in e.g. boost and some other libraries.